# In the sixth adventure, how do you destroy the Gravestorms Phylactery Token?

Tags: castle-ravenloft

You can either kill the dragon by attacking it or by destroying the Gravestorms Phlactery Token.  My question is how do you destroy it.  There are no directions in the rule book or adventure book as how to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 2):

The phylactery doesn't have an AC iirc, so you can essentially destroy it just by attacking it with an at-will.

Comment: Thank you, and everyone else who has put together all the interesting adventures for CR.  they are awesome!